# How can I apply multiple colors to "Lines" in Windows Command Prompt?

Tags: batch-file, windows-10-desktop

I am a newbie here on this website and I would like to ask you how to apply multiple colors by line (or column maybe?) in CMD. Feel free to edit the codes below, I would also like the color of the words to be similar like the classic Google Chrome colors.

```
cls
@echo off
color 0a
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo                                                                                                      ,,
echo                                                         .g8"""bgd                                  `7MM
echo                                                        .dP'    `M                                    MM
echo                                                        dm'      `    ,pW"Wq.    ,pW"Wq.    .P"Ybmmm  MM   .gP"Ya
echo                                                        MM           6W'   `Wb  6W'   `Wb  :MI  I8    MM  ,M'   Yb
echo                                                        MM.   `7MMF' 8M     MB  8M     MB   Wmmmp"    MM  8M""""""
echo                                                        `Mb     MM   YA.   ,A9  YA.   ,A9  8M         MM  YM.    .
echo                                                         `"bmmmdPY    `Ybmd9'    `Ybmd9'    YMMMMMb .JMML. `Mbmmd'
echo                                                                                           6'    dP
echo                                                                                            Ybmmmd'
echo.
echo.
echo.
pause>nul
```

Comment: [choose one](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bbatch-file%5D+different+colors+in+one+line)

Comment: If you want a color function that still works across older versions of Windows you can use  [Color function](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=4881).  Most of the native solutions make use of the `FINDSTR` commands ability to color its output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a somewhat neater looking version of the [windows-10](/questions/tagged/windows-10) ANSI escape code method, already suggested by Gerhard.

```
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions
For /F %%G In ('Echo Prompt $E ^| "%__AppDir__%cmd.exe"') Do Set "ESC=%%G"
ClS
Echo=
Echo=
Echo=
Echo                             %ESC%[92m                                                ,,
Echo                             %ESC%[94m  .g8"""bgd  %ESC%[92m                                 `7MM
Echo                             %ESC%[94m .dP'    `M  %ESC%[92m                                   MM
Echo                             %ESC%[94m dm'      `  %ESC%[91m  ,pW"Wq.  %ESC%[93m  ,pW"Wq. %ESC%[94m  .P"Ybmmm %ESC%[92m   MM  %ESC%[91m  .gP"Ya
Echo                             %ESC%[94m MM          %ESC%[91m 6W'   `Wb %ESC%[93m 6W'   `Wb%ESC%[94m :MI  I8   %ESC%[92m   MM  %ESC%[91m ,M'   Yb
Echo                             %ESC%[94m MM.   `7MMF'%ESC%[91m 8M     MB %ESC%[93m 8M     MB%ESC%[94m  Wmmmp"   %ESC%[92m   MM  %ESC%[91m 8M""""""
Echo                             %ESC%[94m `Mb     MM  %ESC%[91m YA.   ,A9 %ESC%[93m YA.   ,A9%ESC%[94m 8M        %ESC%[92m   MM  %ESC%[91m YM.    .
Echo                             %ESC%[94m  `"bmmmdPY  %ESC%[91m  `Ybmd9'  %ESC%[93m  `Ybmd9' %ESC%[94m  YMMMMMb  %ESC%[92m .JMML.%ESC%[91m  `Mbmmd'
Echo                             %ESC%[94m                                   6'    dP
Echo                                                                 Ybmmmd' %ESC%[0m
Echo=
Echo=
Echo=
Pause 1> NUL
```

You could even mess around with it to put it into a bright white box, for instance:

```
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions
For %%# In (BG FG)Do Set "%%#="
For /F %%# In ('%__AppDir__%WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoP ^
    "$Console=(Get-Host).UI.RawUI;Switch($Console.BackgroundColor," ^
    "$Console.ForegroundColor){'Black'{40}'DarkBlue'{44}'DarkGreen'{42}" ^
    "'DarkCyan'{46}'DarkRed'{41}'DarkMagenta'{45}'DarkYellow'{43}'Gray'{47}" ^
    "'DarkGray'{100}'Blue'{104}'Green'{102}'Cyan'{106}'Red'{101}" ^
    "'Magenta'{105}'Yellow'{103}'White'{107}}" 2^>NUL')Do If Not Defined BG (
    Set "BG=%%#")Else Set "FG=%%#"
For /F %%G In ('Echo Prompt $E ^| "%__AppDir__%cmd.exe"') Do Set "ESC=%%G"
ClS
Echo=
Echo=
Echo=
Echo                             %ESC%[92;107m                                                ,,            %ESC%[%FG%;%BG%m
Echo                             %ESC%[94;107m  .g8"""bgd  %ESC%[92m                                 `7MM            %ESC%[%FG%;%BG%m
Echo                             %ESC%[94;107m .dP'    `M  %ESC%[92m                                   MM            %ESC%[%FG%;%BG%m
Echo                             %ESC%[94;107m dm'      `  %ESC%[91m  ,pW"Wq.  %ESC%[93m  ,pW"Wq. %ESC%[94m  .P"Ybmmm %ESC%[92m   MM  %ESC%[91m  .gP"Ya  %ESC%[%FG%;%BG%m
Echo                             %ESC%[94;107m MM          %ESC%[91m 6W'   `Wb %ESC%[93m 6W'   `Wb%ESC%[94m :MI  I8   %ESC%[92m   MM  %ESC%[91m ,M'   Yb %ESC%[%FG%;%BG%m
Echo                             %ESC%[94;107m MM.   `7MMF'%ESC%[91m 8M     MB %ESC%[93m 8M     MB%ESC%[94m  Wmmmp"   %ESC%[92m   MM  %ESC%[91m 8M"""""" %ESC%[%FG%;%BG%m
Echo                             %ESC%[94;107m `Mb     MM  %ESC%[91m YA.   ,A9 %ESC%[93m YA.   ,A9%ESC%[94m 8M        %ESC%[92m   MM  %ESC%[91m YM.    . %ESC%[%FG%;%BG%m
Echo                             %ESC%[94;107m  `"bmmmdPY  %ESC%[91m  `Ybmd9'  %ESC%[93m  `Ybmd9' %ESC%[94m  YMMMMMb  %ESC%[92m .JMML.%ESC%[91m  `Mbmmd' %ESC%[%FG%;%BG%m
Echo                             %ESC%[94;107m                                   6'    dP                   %ESC%[%FG%;%BG%m
Echo                             %ESC%[94;107m                                    Ybmmmd'                   %ESC%[%FG%;%BG%m
Echo=
Echo=
Echo=
Pause 1> NUL
GoTo :EOF
```

This above method leverages [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell) to determine, and create variables using the current console foreground and background colors. This ensures that they are reset correctly after the color changed image lines have been processed. *(Of course the script writer could just define known colors, right from the outset)*

*I will add however, that the command line is supposed to be for typing commands and reading text output, not for displaying unnecessary childish images and colors. If you want a GUI, build a GUI program, not a console one.*

Comment: Yeah, for the very reason _"..not for displaying unnecessary childish images and colors"_ I did not still format the code to look neat, I just could not find the inspiration :)

Comment: Obviously this example is just for fun/learning, but I hope you aren't implying that using colors in "real" command line applications is *always* unnecessary/childish.

Comment: it works perfectly, thank you Mr. Compo!

Comment: @CMD.EXE you can mark the answer as correct by selecting the grey tick mark to the left of the question, if you feel it suited your requirements.

Comment: @Gerhard, I agree that there was no need for you to extend your example for the purposes of answering the question itself. I only expanded upon it really, to make clear that it is not necessary to use `%ESC%[0m` after each color sequence; thus making the building of the 'graphic' even more difficult due to obfuscation. **0x5453**, my comment does not imply anything, it makes an absolute statement. If you, or others interpret it otherwise, the implication is made by you or them, not by me.

Comment: Yeah, I hear you and agree.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a one way, you'll have to figure out the color refs yourself though, I just added these colors as examples:

```
@echo off
for /F %%a in ('echo prompt $E ^| cmd') do set "ESC=%%a"
cls
echo(
echo(
echo(
echo                                                                                             %ESC%[90m,,%ESC%[0m
echo                                                %ESC%[91m.g8"""bgd%ESC%[0m                                  %ESC%[90m`7MM%ESC%[0m
echo                                                %ESC%[91m.dP'    `M%ESC%[0m                                    %ESC%[90mMM%ESC%[0m
echo                                                %ESC%[91mdm'      `%ESC%[0m    %ESC%[92m,pW"Wq.    ,pW"Wq.%ESC%[0m    %ESC%[90m.P"Ybmmm  MM   .gP"Ya%ESC%[0m
echo                                                %ESC%[91mMM%ESC%[0m           %ESC%[92m6W'   `Wb  6W'   `Wb%ESC%[0m  %ESC%[90m:MI  I8    MM  ,M'   Yb%ESC%[0m
echo                                                %ESC%[91mMM.   `7MMF'%ESC%[0m %ESC%[92m8M     MB  8M     MB%ESC%[0m   %ESC%[90mWmmmp"    MM  8M""""""%ESC%[0m
echo                                                %ESC%[91m`Mb     MM%ESC%[0m   %ESC%[92mYA.   ,A9  YA.   ,A9%ESC%[0m  %ESC%[90m8M         MM  YM.    .%ESC%[0m
echo                                                %ESC%[91m`"bmmmdPY%ESC%[0m    %ESC%[92m`Ybmd9'    `Ybmd9'%ESC%[0m    %ESC%[90mYMMMMMb .JMML. `Mbmmd'%ESC%[0m
echo                                                                                   %ESC%[90m6'    dP%ESC%[0m
echo                                                                                    %ESC%[90mYbmmmd'%ESC%[0m
echo(
echo(
echo(
pause>nul
```

Result:
[image]

**EDIT**

Here is a reference to the [`ansi color`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Colors) escape codes.

Comment: thank you too Mr. Gerhard! it works perfectly

Comment: see the edit at the bottom of the answer as well for the ansi color reference page.